# How many horses are allowed to run a single race?

Tags: rules, horse-racing

What is the maximum number of horses permitted to run a race in the United Kingdom?

Is it different in the USA, or Australia?

Comment: It varies depending upon the capacity of the course.  Also, limits for flat and chase races would be different.  This isn't a question with a single simple answer.